# ''A and B are the same'' vs ''A and B is the same''

Tags: grammar

I found these sentences below in my dictionary.

''His car and mine are the same''

''Is postman and mailman the same?''

Would you please teach me the difference between ''A and B are the same'' and ''A and B is the same''

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "A and B is the same" sounds impossible. Ungrammatical. Are you sure that the dictionary says "Is postman and mailman the same"? Does it not maybe say this: "Is a postman the same as a mailman?"

Comment: @curious-proofreader That *is* what it is. The words are understood to have been in quotes: *Is "postman" and "mailman" the same?*

Comment: This question may be migrated to [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

The reference in the second example is to the words (and their meanings). In plain and simple writing, that is how it is written.

However, one should understand it as meaning

> Do the words "postman" and "mailman" mean the same?

or

> Is it one and the same thing that we call variously as "postman" and "mailman"?

It is grammatical in that the speaker presumes that it is so.

Compare the case when the listener may reply:

> No they **are** not the same.

which is also correct, just as the following is

> No it **is** not the same.